# Reconocer imagenes desde una url - Expresiones Regulares

Tags: php, funciones, php7

Tengo una funcion en la cual reconoce las url

```
<?php
function findReplaceURL($text){
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
    return preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href=".$url[0]."target='_blank'>".$url[0]."</a>", $text);
    } else {
        return $text;
    }
}
?>
```

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que reconozca, no solo las url de un sitio sino también las imágenes que terminan en jpg, png y gif que provienen de una url. Trate de usar esta expresión: `"%(?<=src=\")([^\"])+(png|jpg|gif)%i"`, pero no consigo resultados.

Comment: Hola, has probado en el foro en ingles? Te dejo este enlace con comentarios muy curiosos que podrian servirte: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif/169631

Comment: gracias, pero supongamos que tengo esta expresion: `^((http(s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?([\w]+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?((/?\w+/)+|/?)(\w+\.(jpg|png|gif))`, el problema esta cuando agrego una url con una imagen y no veo la misma, solo la url que me lleva a esa imagen

Comment: lo que no logro hacer en la funcion es una condicion en la que me guarde la url y al traerla me indique si es una imagen asi `<img srv="http://www.web.com/imagen.jpg">` o si es solo una pagina web asi: `<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con dos expresiones regulares entiendo que la función cumple su misión. Primero detectamos si es una url, si es así, preguntamos si es una imagen y de serlo le pone el tag correcto.

He metido la función en un script de línea de comandos y el resultado creo que es satisfactorio ;-)

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
function findReplaceURL($text)
{
    $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
    $reg_exImg = "/.*(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/";

    if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url1)) 
    {
        if(preg_match($reg_exImg, $text, $url2))
        {
            return preg_replace($reg_exImg, "<img src='".$url2[0]."' />", $text);
        }
        else
        {
            return preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href='".$url1[0]."' target='_blank'>".$url1[0]."</a>", $text);
        }
    }   
    else 
    {
        return $text;
    }
}

$urls = array("http://yahoo.es","http://prueba.com/imagen.png","ftp://prueba2.com/");

foreach($urls as $url)
{
    echo findReplaceURL($url)."\n";
}
```

salida:

```
<a href='http://yahoo.es' target='_blank'>http://yahoo.es</a>
<img src='http://prueba.com/imagen.png' />
<a href='ftp://prueba2.com/' target='_blank'>ftp://prueba2.com/</a>
```

Comment: Entendi, yo estaba haciendo un `elseif` y bueno, estaba haciendo todo mail. Muchas gracias @neoniet